# Mean Value Theorem question (show that f is constant)

Tags: derivatives, continuity, mean-value-theorem

> Suppose that $f, g : R → R$ are functions such that
>
> $$|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |g(x) − g(y)| \sqrt{|x − y|}$$ for any $x, y ∈ R$.
> If $g$ is differentiable with bounded derivative on all $R$, show that
> $f$ is constant.

I know I am meant to be using MVT for this question, I attempted to use $g(x)$ as the function because we know it is differentiable (condition required for MVT):
$$\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=g'(c)$$
$$|g(b)-g(a)|=|g'(c)|b-a|$$
I am lost, not sure where to start the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the derivative of $g$ is bounded as $|g'(c)| \le M$ for all $c$, then
$$\left| \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \right| \le \frac{|g(x)-g(y)|}{\sqrt{|x-y|}}
\le M \sqrt{|x-y|}$$
for any $x,y$, where the last inequality is from your application of the mean value theorem. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am not sure how you got the denominator in $\|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\|$...

Comment: @JohnWarts I took the inequality given in the problem and divided both sides by $|x-y|$.

Comment: and then after this step, I can say that f'(x) is smaller than M so it must be constant since $f'(x) = \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$

Comment: @JohnWarts Every part of your comment is wrong... First, $f'(x) \ne \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$.  Second, we haven't concluded $f'(x)$ is smaller than $M$. Finally, even if we did show $f'(x)$ is smaller than $M$, that isn't enough to conclude that $f$ is constant.